# Customizing the radial menu

Tags: alien-swarm

I want to bind some complex combinations of voice, text and emotes to the radial menu for quick communication. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radial menu is defined in `Steam\steamapps\common\alien swarm\swarm\scripts\radialmenu.txt`, you can edit this file to change its functionality.

The radial menu has 9 items, which are defined by their position: Center, North, NorthEast, etc. Each item has command and text properties - text is how the item shows up in the radial menu, command is executed when you select it in-game. You can chain multiple commands with a semicolon.

The commands you will likely want to use are **say** (followed by some text, no quotes necessary), cl_emote (followed by one of the emote codes, display an emote) and cl_chatter (followed by a chatter code, makes your marine say one of his lines).

Emote codes

```
0 - Medic!
1 - Out of ammo
2 - Smile
3 - Hold position
4 - Follow me
5 - Be careful
6 - Anime smile
7 - Ready?
```

Chatter codes (only relevant ones, see [full list here](http://alienswarm.wikia.com/wiki/Console_commands#Voice_Chatter))

```
-1 - miscChat1
 0 - acknowledge1
 1 - miscChat2
 2 - acknowledge2
 3 - miscChat3
 4 - friendlyFire1
 5 - incoming1
 6 - moveOut1
 7 - holdPosition1
 8 - requestAmmo1
 9 - noAmmo1
10 - requestMedic1
11 - reloading1
12 - sentryReady1
13 - announceAmmo1
14 - announceMedkit1
15 - thanks1
16 - what1
26 - announceSupplies1
27 - announceAmmoSupplies1
32 - holdingPosition1
33 - northCovered1
34 - southCovered1
35 - eastCovered1
36 - westCovered1
37 - front1
38 - rear1
39 - requestWeld1
40 - requestUnweld1
41 - requestShootDoor1
42 - announceUnweld1
43 - announceWeld1
44 - announceBiomass
45 - objectiveComplete1
46 - warn1
47 - warnShieldbug1
48 - shootBehind1
49 - warnParasite1
50 - requestParasite1
51 - warnEggs1
52 - warnGrenade1          (Cannot be said by Wildcat.)
53 - requestHostile1
54 - tauntSwarm1
55 - doorBreached1
56 - marineDown1
57 - scream1
58 - scream2
59 - scream3
60 - screamFire1
61 - goodJob1              (Cannot be said by Faith, Jaeger, or Wolfe.)
62 - activateStims1
99 - reluctantAgreement1
```

Example custom radial menu

```
"RadialMenu"
{
   //--------------------------------------------------------------
   "Default"
   {
      "Center"
      {
         "command"   "cl_emote 6; cl_chatter 15; say Thanks mate!"
         "text"      "^_^"
      }
      "North"
      {
         "command"   "cl_chatter 33"
         "text"      "Covering North"
      }
      "NorthEast"
      {
         "command"   "asw_OrderMarinesFollow"
         "text"      "#asw_speech_go"
      }   
      "East"
      {
         "command"   "cl_chatter 35"
         "text"      "Covering East"
      }   
      "SouthEast"
      {
         "command"   "asw_OrderMarinesHold"
         "text"      "#asw_speech_hold"
      }   
      "South"
      {
         "command"   "cl_chatter 34"
         "text"      "Covering South"
      }
      "SouthWest"
      {
         "command"   "cl_chatter 37"
         "text"      "Taking Point"
      }
      "West"
      {
         "command"   "cl_chatter 36"
         "text"      "Covering West"
      }
      "NorthWest"
      {
         "command"   "cl_emote 5"
         "text"      "#asw_speech_careful"
      }   
   }
}
```

In this example the central item will display a smiling emote, have you marine say thanks and write "Thanks mate!" to chat, cardinal direction items will announce that you are covering these directions, top left will display a warning sign and have your marine urge caution, bottom left will have your marine announce he is taking point, top right will display the "Go" emote and bottom right will display the "Stop" emote.

Comment: I know it's been a while ;) but I've just started getting back into AS:RD. Is it possible to create several radial menus?